# Using regex to match any character until a substring is reached?

Tags: c#, regex, vb.net

I'd like to be able to match a specific sequence of characters, starting with a particular substring and ending with a particular substring.  My positive lookahead regex works if there is only one instance to match on a line, but not if there should be multiple matches on a line.  I understand this is because (.+) captures up everything until the *last* positive lookahead expression is found.  It'd be nice if it would capture everything until the *first* expression is found.

Here is my regex attempt:

```
@@FOO\[(.*)(?=~~)~~(.*)(?=\]@@)\]@@
```

Sample input:

```
@@FOO[abc~~hi]@@    @@FOO[def~~hey]@@
```

Desired output: 2 matches, with 2 matching groups each (abc, hi) and (def, hey).

Actual output: 1 match with 2 groups (abc~~hi]@@        @@FOO[def, hey)

Is there a way to get the desired output?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the question mark, it will match as few times as possible.

```
@@FOO\[(.*?)(?=~~)~~(.*?)(?=\]@@)\]@@
```

This one also works but is not as strict although easier to read

```
@@FOO\[(.*?)~~(.*?)\]@@
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for!  When researching this I was focused so much on the grouping constructs I completely overlooked *?

Comment: I actually almost always use `.*?` instead of just `.*` because I almost never mean "match as much as possible"

Answer (score 3):

The * operator is [greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) by default, meaning it eats up as much of the string as possible while still leaving enough to match the remaining regex. You can make it not greedy by appending a ? to it. Make sure to read about the differences at the link.

Comment: Thanks.  In years of using regex for various languages, I never knew about *?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the **String.IndexOf()** method instead to find the first occurrence of your substring.